# Csv format easy colums characteristic - type dataset for beginner R analisys

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, programming

I had a look on kaggle but I did not find what I was looking for. I need a very simple data set, like the one of "iris" default pre-sets of R where you have differents columns with some characteristic of the plant such as length and so on and where the last column tells you the type of species. There is an analogous dataset, for example about rocks, where may be some columns tells a characteristic such as permeablity and so on, and the last column tells you the type of the rock. I need to practice an easy data analysis to be performed with R (for an exam). I could not find somethin like iris neither on the R dataset.

Comment: As you realized, the datasets package that ships with any basic R installation gives you many different types of datasets (see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/00Index.html for documentation). Are you saying that among the ~100 datasets, you cannot find anything  that suits your needs? I think, then you'd have to be more specific about the type of data analysis you are trying to play with.

Comment: Maybe OP means it has to come from a csv file (in regards to title)??

Comment: I am going to work on it as a dataframe format